# Crazy issue with setting up eclipse for android development

Tags: android, eclipse, android-support-library

I've really searched and could't find a solution for the problem, so i'm using eclipse, if i try to create a new android application project and choose full screen activity it tells me that the template depends on android support library which is either not installed or old, when i click the install/update button to solve the issue it says android support jar (android-support-v4.jar) not found, i've seen videos about modifying the build path... but i can't even create the project to change its build path, any ideas about how to solve the issue?!!

[image: here is a pic to make it more clear]

Comment: Why don't you use a recent version of Android Studio?

Comment: What was the last time ADT plugin was updated? 8 years ago?

Comment: Eclipse has not been supported for Android development for a long time now. Use Android Studio

Comment: You reaaaaally shouldn't be using the Android Support Library in 2021, either.  Getting up-to-date templates would be yet another benefit of using Android Studio.

Comment: @hata because it's a bit slow, my laptop doesn't give a smooth experience with it despite that i have an i5 8th gen processor

Comment: @serhaniahmedsaned Even if so, the fact that *it's now not a supported environment*, I think, is bigger problem than a performance issue, as some people commented.